# Vite doesn't resolve extension for build

Tags: webpack, vite, laravel-mix

I tre to migrate from laravel-mix to vite by [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpOj3Ad4hV4&t=267s)

When i run `npm run dev` (`vite`), everything is great.

But when i run `npm run build`, i get the error:

> Error: Could not load resources/js/hooks/useRoute (imported by resources/js/app.tsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\OpenServer\domains\colorbit.local\reso
> urces\js\hooks\useRoute'

It's because i import all files without extensions. PhpStorm said that this is how it should be, if you add an extension, then it gave an error that it’s better not to do this. So I used imports without file extension everywhere in the project.

How to ignore extensions when importing files? How should i change my vite.config.js?
Example: `import {Button} from '@componenst/ui/Button` - not `.ts` extension.

Here's the code

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.tsx',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({
            fastRefresh: false
        }),

    ],
    resolve: {
        alias     : {
            '@'          : 'resources/js',
            '@assets'    : 'resources/js/assets',
            '@hooks'     : 'resources/js/hooks',
            '@components': 'resources/js/components'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
    },
});

// package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "ssr": "mix --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js",
        "routes": "php artisan ziggy:generate",
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.3",
        "@inertiajs/server": "^0.1.0",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.0-rc.0",
        "@prettier/plugin-php": "^0.18.5",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
        "@types/ziggy-js": "^1.3.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.6",
        "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
        "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.52.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
        "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.7.2",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-react": "^0.8.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "laravel-vite": "^0.0.24",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
        "react-joyride": "^2.5.3",
        "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.4",
        "ziggy-js": "^1.4.6"
    }
}


// Index.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {{--  MANIFEST  --}}
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

    {{--  ICONS  --}}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Colorbit') }}</title>

    <!-- CSRF -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @routes
    @vite
    @inertiaHead
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia
</body>
</html>

// resources/js/app.tsx
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layouts/Layout";
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import {InertiaProgress} from '@inertiajs/progress';
import axios from 'axios';
import {RouteContext} from '@hooks/useRoute';
import {initPush} from "./enable-push";

import '../css/app.scss';
import {resolvePageComponent} from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";

window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

const appName =
    window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'ColorBit';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title: string) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: async (name: string) => {
        const page = (await resolvePageComponent<any>(
            `./Pages/${name}.tsx`,
            import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.tsx'
        ))).default;

        page.layout = page.layout || ((page: React.ReactElement) => <Layout children={page}/>);

        return page;
    },
    setup({el, App, props}) {
        const root = createRoot(el);
        return root.render(
            <React.StrictMode>
                <RouteContext.Provider value={(window as any).route || 123}>
                    <App {...props} />
                </RouteContext.Provider>
            </React.StrictMode>
        );
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({color: '#CC3824'});
```

Comment: @AhmedSbai idk, that's a base config for vue, i have tried alomist idetical config but without vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally fixed this. The problem was in alias paths - not in extensions.
In dev mode all was right, but `npm run build` throw the error. I though that aliases is tight but only for peace of mind i added `path.resolve`.
I was very surprized that it helped.

Conclusion: use `path.resolve`;)

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.tsx',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({
            fastRefresh: false
        }),

    ],
    resolve: {
        alias     : {
            '@'          : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
            '@hooks'     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/hooks'),
            '@assets'    : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/assets/'),
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got the error `Cannot find module '/.../myapp/node_modules/mylib/bar/Foo'` and thought that the extension is the problem (given that it's Foo.js, of course), but it was the path, like in your case.

I had the problem with a library that belongs to my project and is in a sibling directory. So, I was able to fix it similar to you:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "mylib": path.resolve("../mylib/")
    },
  },
});
```

given that `mylib/` is in a sibling directory to `myapp/`.

Thank you for posting your problem and your solution.

Answer (score 0):

something that works for me was to change `__dirname` with `new URL(import.meta.url).pathname` so eslint dont tell you about __dirname is not defined, i was using vite+react+js

```
resolve: {
  alias     : {
    '@'          : path.resolve(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, './src'),
    '@routes'    : path.resolve(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, '../src/routes'),
    '@assets'    : path.resolve(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, '../src/assets'),
    '@components': path.resolve(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, '../src/components')
  },
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
},
```